# Angular zip observables of different types

Tags: angular

I want to zip two observables which are of different types

```
interface IFirstType{
    id: number;
    name: string;
    firstdescription: string;
}

interface ISecondType{
    id: number;
    name: string;
    seconddescription: string
}

this.FirstTypeOB$ = this.firstTypeService.all();
this.SecondTypeOB$ = this.secondTypeService.all();


zip( this.FirstTypeOB$, this.SecondTypeOB$ )
 .pipe(
   map( x => x[ 0 ].concat( x[ 1 ] ) ) // error here
 .subscribe();
```

I get an error

```
"Argument of type 'ISecondType[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ConcatArray<IFirstType>'"
```

I understand that the two are of different types but how can I zip the two using only id and name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can lose type with explicitly converting arrays to `any[]` or `(IFirstType | ISecondType)[]` or `Array<IFirstType | ISecondType>`; but is it fine? how are you going to work with these types later?

to fix here you can do

```
 map( (x: Array<Array<IFirstType | ISecondType>> ) => x[ 0 ].concat( x[ 1 ] ) )
```

Comment: Could you please show with any example code as to how I can change the observable type? I only want to use id and name and will not use this type later

Comment: provided an example in answer

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of spread operator

`map(([firstType, secondType]) => [...firstType, ...secondType])`